Can you suggest some improvements to this logo?

A logo for high school with focus on math n science.
Can you suggest some improvements to this logo?

Thank you for your comments. I have made some changes accordingly.
One more element is added: the letter Psi.
I am wondering if this is more confiusing or should I get back to 3 elements only in the center.
Which is the best? Should the three elements (pi, flask, tube) be in continuous path or scattered?




Hey Epa. Please edit your question to be more specific and follow our critique guidelines or your question will likely be closed

This is only my personal opinion, and others may have a different take on this. However, I think the basic design of the logo is fine, but there are several issues that need to be fixed and cleaned up.

All of the lines are far too thin, and some are even different weights, and the text around the ring is not bold enough. If you reduce the size of the logo, some of the lines could disappear, and the text could become unreadable. It's always a good idea to test your logo at different sizes. Try to keep the line weight and text weight similar and consistent.

The text is not rotated properly and so it looks unbalanced (not symmetrical). Also, it's not centred within the ring.

The text "TRUNG HOC" is upside down. This is a big no-no for readability.

The graphic in the middle isn't in centred, and the edge of the flask is too near to the edge of the ring. More space around the entire graphic would help here.

Use some guides to help you keep everything centred; to help with the spacing and rotation, etc.

The PI symbol isn't symmetrical.

Not sure I like the large "Konigsburgh" text underneath. The name is already in the logo, so it seems redundant to repeat it. If you do want to keep it, I would move it down from the logo. It's far too close.


Here's an example showing the suggested fixes:

